# Contract first spring web services

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-ws

I am new to spring web service and with help of tutorial I made a simple web service but when I am trying to test it on soapui its not responding any output.

I attached all required things here please help me where I lost.

**XML Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.servesy-ws.com/services" xmlns:tns="http://www.servesy-ws.com/services" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:element name="SignupRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="SignupResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="response" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

**maven dependencies**

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.ws.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
    <context.path>spring-webservices-sample</context.path>
</properties>
<build>
<finalName>servesy-web</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/schemas</schemaDirectory>
                <includeSchema>**/*.xsd</includeSchema>
                <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/bindings</bindingDirectory>
                <enableIntrospection>false</enableIntrospection>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${context.path}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Service interface**

```
package com.ws.servesy;

    public interface SignupService {

        public String response(String name);

}
```

**Service Implementation**

```
package com.ws.servesy;

public class SignupServiceImpl implements SignupService {

    public String response(String name) {

        return name;
    }

}
```

**Endpoint**

```
package com.ws.endpoint;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import com.servesy_ws.services.SignupRequest;
import com.servesy_ws.services.SignupResponse;
import com.ws.servesy.SignupService;


@Endpoint
public class SignupServiceEndpoint {

    private static final String TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://www.servesy-ws.com/services";

    @Autowired
    private SignupService signupservice;

    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "SignupRequest", namespace = TARGET_NAMESPACE)
    public @ResponsePayload SignupResponse getname(@RequestPayload SignupRequest request) {
        SignupResponse signupresponse = new SignupResponse();
        String name = signupservice.response(request.getName());
        signupresponse.setResponse(name);
        return signupresponse;

    }
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/endpoints/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Spring Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ws.servesy" />
    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <!--
        Our test service bean
    -->
    <bean id="SignupService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="schemaCollection">
            <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
                <property name="inline" value="true" />
                <property name="xsds">
                    <list>
                        <value>schemas/servesy-ws.xsd</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="portTypeName" value="SignupService"/>
        <property name="serviceName" value="SignupServices" />
        <property name="locationUri" value="/endpoints"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**and generated wsdl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.servesy-ws.com/services" xmlns:tns="http://www.servesy-ws.com/services" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:sch="http://www.servesy-ws.com/services" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
   -<wsdl:types>
       -<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.servesy-ws.com/services"
         elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            -<xsd:element name="SignupRequest">
             -<xsd:complexType>
              -<xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
               </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
             </xsd:element>
          -<xsd:element name="SignupResponse">
             -<xsd:complexType>
               -<xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="response" type="xsd:string"/>
                 </xsd:sequence>
               </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
      </xsd:schema>
 </wsdl:types>
    -<wsdl:message name="SignupResponse">
      <wsdl:part name="SignupResponse" element="tns:SignupResponse"> </wsdl:part></wsdl:message>
    -<wsdl:message name="SignupRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="SignupRequest" element="tns:SignupRequest"> 
 </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
      -<wsdl:portType name="SignupService">
        -<wsdl:operation name="Signup">
           <wsdl:input name="SignupRequest" message="tns:SignupRequest"> </wsdl:input>
           <wsdl:output name="SignupResponse" message="tns:SignupResponse"> </wsdl:output>
       </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:portType>
         -<wsdl:binding name="SignupServiceSoap11" type="tns:SignupService">
         <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        -<wsdl:operation name="Signup">
           <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
          -<wsdl:input name="SignupRequest">
             <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        -<wsdl:output name="SignupResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
           </wsdl:output>
          </wsdl:operation>
         </wsdl:binding>
        -<wsdl:service name="SignupServices">
            -<wsdl:port name="SignupServiceSoap11" binding="tns:SignupServiceSoap11">
               <soap:address location="http://localhost:9999/servesy-web/endpoints"/>
           </wsdl:port>
         </wsdl:service>
        </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Please also post the output from your log-file.

Comment: @KurtDuBois I attached my wsdl please see it.